# Как сравнить два массива типа char с помощью рекурсии

Tags: c++

как можно сравнить два массива типа `char` с помощью рекурсии?

Comment: Что значит "часовых"?

Comment: предположу, что числовых :)

Comment: @TheNorthon char[]) сорри) автозамена подвела

Answer (score 2):

Любителям однострочных тернистых выражений посвящается:

```
bool cmp(const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
    return *s1 == *s2 ? *s1 ? cmp(++s1, ++s2) : true : false;
}
```

P.S. Don't try this at home

Comment: я бы ещё сократил `return *s1 == *s2 && (!*s1 ||cmp(++s1, ++s2) );` . А что тут такого что дома повторять нельзя?

Comment: @pavel, код ужасен. За такое морду бьют в приличном обществе, поэтому и приписка.

Comment: @pavel вложенные тернарки (и вообще длинные однострочные коды) сложны для прочтения и понимания. Ну и не стоит использовать рекурсию там, где место циклу. Хотя здесь, конечно, требования вытекают из вопроса.

Comment: @alexolut ну от тернарника я вроде бы избавился. А стал ли от этого код понятнее?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

bool compare(const char* s1, const char* s2){
    bool res;
    if(*s1 && (*s1 == *s2)) 
        res = compare(s1 + 1, s2 + 1);
    else
        res = (!*s1 && !*s2);
    return res;
 }

 int main(void){
    char s1[] = "PASCAL";
    char s2[] = "PASCAL";

    if(compare(s1, s2))
       std::cout << "Равны." << std::endl;
    else
       std::cout << "Неравно!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

пока ждал ответ на неправильно заданный вопрос, сам и написал его)

```
bool is_equal(char a[],char b[]) {
    if (a[0] == '\0' && b[0] == '\0') {
        return true;
    } else if (a[0] != b[0]) {
        return false;
    }
    return is_equal(a+1,b+1);
}
```

Comment: Минусы: 1. Название фукнции в стиле "масло-маслянное", т.е. 'char_array' лишнее, т.е. из аргументов понятно, что это массивы 2. Функция не безопасно, желательно передать максимальное-кол-во символов, посмотрите _s аналоги в си-документации

Comment: спасибо @sys_dev

Comment: обратите внимание на такой тип данных как string. Он избавит от всех проблем сравнения и изобретения велосипедов.

Comment: @V.Rotenberh та я бы удовольствием, но профессору с универа надо именно такое извращение